# Cannot connect Thymeleaf HTML webpage to my Spring Boot API/DB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application for a school records management system. My API is working perfectly when using Insomnia but I cannot get my hTML webpage to interact with the API. Here are the relevant bits of my Staff entity/controller/repository/service. Any help appreciated!

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class Staff {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "STAFF_SEQ",
            sequenceName = "STAFF_SEQ",
           allocationSize = 1
     )
    @GeneratedValue(
       strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
      generator = "STAFF_SEQ"
    )
    private Long staffId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String staffEmail;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class)
    private Long departmentId;
    private String address;
        private String contactNumber;
        private char gender;
    
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Controller Class

```
    @RestController
    public class StaffController {
    
        @Autowired
        private StaffService staffService;
    
        @RequestMapping(value = "/saveStaff")
        public Staff saveStaff(Staff staff) {
            return staffService.saveStaff(staff);
        }
   ...
}
```

Repository Class

```
@Repository
public interface StaffRepository extends JpaRepository<Staff, Long> {
    Staff findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);
}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface StaffService {

    public Staff saveStaff(Staff staff);
  ...
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class StaffServiceImpl implements StaffService{

    @Autowired
    StaffRepository staffRepository;

    @Override
    public Staff saveStaff(Staff staff) {
       return staffRepository.save(staff);
    }
...
}
```

HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">

<h2>Add Staff</h2>

<form action = "#" method="post" th:action ="@{/saveStaff}" th:object = "${staff}">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Staff</legend>
    <label for="firstName">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" th:field ="*{firstName}" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
    <label for="lastName">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" th:field ="*{lastName}" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastname"><br><br>
    <label for="staffEmail">Staff email:</label><br>
    <input type="staffEmail" th:field ="*{staffEmail}" class="form-control" id="staffEmail" name="staffEmail"> <br><br>
    <label for="address">Address</label><br>
    <input type="text" th:field ="*{address}" class="form-control" id="address" name="address"><br><br>
    <label for="contactNumber"> Contact number</label><br>
    <input type="text" th:field ="*{contactNumber}" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber"><br><br>
    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <select th:field ="*{gender}" class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender">
        <option value="f">F</option>
        <option value="m">M</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <label for="departmentId"> Department Id</label><br>
    <input type="number" th:field ="*{departmentId}" class="form-control" id="departmentId" name="departmentId"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to remove `action = "#" ` in <form>

Answer (score 1):

Your controller class is a `@RestController`. From view page you need to call the rest controller by using `XmlHttpRequest` or we can say, Ajax request or fetch API. For your ease, you can try jQuery. If you really want to submit your form the `Thymeleaf` way, then your controller needs to be a MVC Controller. Long story short, you should replace the annotation `@RestController` with `@Controller`. Also remove the `action` attribute and keep only `th:action`.

**Your Controller class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/course")
public class CourseController {

    @Autowired
    CourseService courseService;

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String get_saveCourseForm(Model model) {
        Course course = new Course();
        model.addAttribute("course", course);
        return "saveCourse";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String post_saveCourseForm(@ModelAttribute("course") Course course, Model model) {
        courseService.saveCourse(course);
        var courses = courseService.fetchCourseList();
        model.addAttribute("courses", courses);
        return "displayCourses";
    }
}
```

1. Replaced `@RestController` with `@Controller` annotation

[image]

2. Add MVC methods and return view page names from the MVC methods. Also notice the request mappings. We will view the form by calling `/course/add` and the form will be submitted to `/course/save`.

[image]

**Your Form Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">

<h2>Add Course</h2>

<form method="post" th:action ="@{/course/save}" th:object = "${course}">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Staff</legend>
        <label for="courseName">Course name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" th:field ="*{courseName}" class="form-control" id="courseName" name="courseName"><br><br>
        <label for="courseCode">Course code:</label><br>
        <input type="text" th:field ="*{courseCode}" class="form-control" id="courseCode" name="courseCode"><br><br>
        <label for="departmentId"> Department Id</label><br>
        <input type="number" th:field ="*{departmentId}" class="form-control" id="departmentId" name="departmentId"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the form action.

[image]

The page will look like below.

[image]

When the form will be submitted, it will return the result page. the HTML code is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Display Courses</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Course ID</th>
        <th>Course Name</th>
        <th>Course Code</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="course : ${courses}">
        <td><span th:text="${course.courseId}"></span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${course.courseName}"></span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${course.courseCode}"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The page will look as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've tried this and there was no change.

Comment: Okay, I will try it in my local, and let you know. Can you share your git repo?

Comment: Thank you! https://github.com/FrancescaLundvall/IndustryProjectFrancescaLundvall

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can check it. I hope it will help.